# T-SQL Update Table using current columns as input parameters of function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to update table columns using a function. The input parameters of the function are data fields from the table that I want to update.

Let's say I have table with two columns ("Country" and "Capital"). The "Capital" is entered and I am using a function that returns a county name by capital name as input parameter. So, my update code is something like this:

```
UPDATE @TableName
SET Country=(SELECT Country FROM dbo.fn_GetCountryByCapital(Capital))
```

There is no error generated by IntelliSence,but on F5 press it say:

> Incorrect syntax near 'Capital'.

Please, note that this is just a example (because it may looks to you silly). I  give it sample in order to describe my problem. My real situation includes the use of several functions in the update statement.

Thank you in advance for the help.
Joro

Possible Solution:

I have found other way to do this. It does not look so good, but it works:

- I have added index in my temp table in order to use while statement
- For each record in the table (using while statement) I have used temp variables to store the field information I have need
- Then I have passed this information to my functions and the outcome I have used to update the table

My guess is that the brackets '( )' that surrounded the select statement and the function do not allowed the function to use the correct values from the table.

Comment: Capital should be parameter. Do you want to update all rows of Country country with value return from your function?

Comment: Yes, I know :-]. I have written the rest function. If you do 
    Update TableName
    Set Field1=Field2
It works. So, why i can not pass Field2 to my function?

Comment: Are you passing Capital as parameter, right? If so, should be parameter @Capital?

Comment: @Thit Lwin Oo, I get the value if the "Capital" from the current row of the table. This mean, "Capital" is a column in the table that I am updating.

Answer (score 0):

**learn the right way (most efficient) to build SQL**:

```
UPDATE a
    SET Country=b.Country
    FROM @TableName a
    INNER JOIN YourCountryCapitalTable b ON a.Capital=b.Capital
```

you can not code SQL like an application program, you need to use set logic and NOT per row logic.  When you throw a bunch of functions into a SQL statement they *most likely* will need to be run per row, slowing down your queries (unless they are table functions in your FROM clause).  If just incorporate the function into the query you can **most likely see massive performance improvements** because of index usage and operations occur on the complete and not row per row.

it is sad to have to very sql code that isn't elegant and often repeats itself all over the place.  however, your main sql goal is fast data retrieval (index usage and set operations) and not some fancy coding beauty contest.

`I have found other way to do this.` yuck yuck yuck, sounds like a future question here on SO when the next person needs to maintain this code.  You don't need an index to use a `WHILE`.  If you have so many rows in your temp table that you need an index, a `WHILE` is the **LAST** thing you should be doing!

Comment: What the hell dude? DO you think if there is way not to use functions but Update with INNER JOIN i won't do it? Do you read my post and understand in what situation am I? 

Something more, I do not want performance here. I have a large amount if data that I should modified,update,etc, but only once time. The result will be a normal table. I am doing manipulation over the data for once...

Comment: I missed in your question where you say this is a "one time" run. I reread your question and still didn't see where you said that this was a one time run.  You say `DO you think if there is way not to use functions but Update with INNER JOIN i won't do it?` however you post a question about an `Incorrect syntax near ...` error.  I figure if you can't read the manual then you don't know SQL very well. I guess my bad.  anyway, if this is a one time run, then looping is fine if you have enough time for this to run.

Comment: for this one time run, I'd still prefer as much set based processing as possible, try using temp tables to hold intermediate values, `OUTPUT` can be very help full in these situations.

Comment: True, and I am using it. But sometimes you can not do the things in a easy, good-looking way. No matter, after all the answer is that using () around select statement isolated it from the current update columns.